# Not able to send records from kinesis firehose to private redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, vpn, amazon-vpc, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have a use case where my redshift cluster is private and supports only VPN connection to the VPC. I need to send data from kinesis firehose which is in another VPC. I found out that we need to make redshift public or attach an internet gateway to make this happen but I can't use internet gateway. I need to connect to redshift from kinesis firehose with VPN only. I am not able to figure out any way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are already aware, you cannot use a private Redshift cluster in a VPC as a target for Firehose without Internet access.  There is no direct solution for this as [detailed here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/controlling-access.html#using-iam-rs) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/troubleshooting.html#data-not-delivered-to-rs).

That said, I can think of at least two work arounds that might suffice.

1. You can have Firehose target S3.  Then setup a private link access to S3 from the private VPC and setup an event to copy the data into the Redshift cluster on an acceptable cadence.  I think this is probably the best option.
2. You *MIGHT* be able to setup Firehose with a lambda processor that feeds the records into Redshift.  The reason I say "might" is because the lambda will also need to be within the VPC and will need to be able to keep up with the Firehose flow.  This could be fraught with performance issues, and potentially expensive.  And Redshift isn't really meant to have high write transactions as a data warehouse.  This is the worst option.

Answer (score 2):

Firehose aggregates data in S3 and then triggers a COPY command in Redshift.  As you don't have a network path from Firehose to Redshift this fails.  However, Firehose can just stop at placing the data in S3.

Now you just need a way to trigger Redshift to COPY the data.  There are a number of ways to do this but the easiest way is to use Lambda (in your Redshift VPC) to issue the COPY commands.  You will need to decide on when the Lambda should run - Firehose uses two parameters to determine when a COPY should be issued; time since last COPY and data size not yet copied.  You can emulate this behavior if you like but the simplest way is to just issue COPYs on some regular time interval, like every 5 min.

To do this you set up CloudWatch to trigger your Lambda every 5 min.  The

1. Lambda looks in the Firehose location in S3 and  lists all the files
2. renames (moves) all these files to put them in a new uniquely named
   S3 "subfolder"
3. issues the COPY command to Redshift to ingest from this "subfolder"
4. Upon successful ingestion these files can be moved again, left in
   the above "subfolder" or deleted

The reason to rename/move the files in S3 is to ensure that each run of the Lambda is operating on a unique set of files and that files aren't ingested more than once.

Comment: Yes, this seems a good alternative but the only problem is it creates more lag for the records to be available in redshift. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: You could COPY in each Firehose file once it is created in S3 by defining an event on create which triggers the ingestion Lambda.  This would ingest objects w/ nearly zero delay (possibly faster than firehose to Redshift) but ingesting small sets of data into Redshift is not efficient.  You can also define triggers between these extremes to match your needs.

Comment: @VikasShaw Redshift is a data warehouse meant for OLAP.  You shouldn't be very concerned about fast writes and lag as that's not what it's good at.  If you need something more transactional, look at Kinesis > Lambda > Aurora.